# php array conversion instead of number put name

Tags: php, arrays

How can i change an array like the below one --->

```
$data = Array
(
    [1] => Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB
    [4] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
)
```

to this --->

```
    $data = Array
        (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-N7100 Galaxy Note II 16GB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
        )
```

Comment: You can't. The keys are not unique.

Comment: @JohnConde can you suggest any solution

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: @Alex it's heard to explain why i need that, but i need the document to be address as a name

Comment: If you don't know why you need it, then you don't need it. What would you do with `$data`?

Comment: @Federico sorry for explaining it properly, i have update my question what i want, can you kindly have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it, here it is:

```
$data = array
(
   'Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB',
   'Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II'
);

$new_arr=array();


foreach ($data as $val) {

    $new_arr[]['name'] = $val;
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can suggest is to transform your array:

```
$data = array
(
    '1' => 'Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB',
    '4' => 'Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II'
);
$newData = array();

foreach ($data as $key=>$val ) {
    $newData[$key]['name'] =$val;
}
```

So now you walk through `$newData` and catch `name` as a field:

```
foreach ($newData as $obj ) {
     echo $obj['name'];
}
```

Comment: you are awesome with your answer, thump UP :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
    1 => 'Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB',
    4 => 'Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II'
);

$newData = array_map(function ($e) {
    return array('name' => $e);
}, array_values($data));

var_dump($newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), i.e.:

```
$array =  array("Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB", "Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II");
$newarray = array();
foreach($array  as $model){
array_push($newarray, array('name' => $model) );
}
print_r($newarray);
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
        )

)
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/QTqAjr